# Upload a file using WWW::Selenium

Tags: perl, selenium, upload, automation

Can someone tell me how can I upload a file using the Upload button in a website?

**HTML Source for upload button**

```
<div id="upload-import-link" class="qq-upload-button string-file-import" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; direction: ltr;">
<input type="file" multiple="multiple" name="file" style="position: absolute; right: 0pt; top: 0pt; font-family: Arial; font-size: 118px; margin: 0pt; padding: 0pt; cursor: pointer; opacity: 0;">
```

This is the Upload button behavior.
When I click 'Upload' button, the pop-up window opens to select the file.
As soon as I select the file, it gets uploaded.
How do I automate this behavior?

Comment: I don't believe selenium supports navigating file menus to upload a file. You could get around this by having a text box that the file menu populates with a file path following which the user clicks an upload button. Then, instead of navigating the file windows, you can just do a sendKeys on the text field with the absolute file path of the desired file to upload.

Comment: @AndyPerfect - can you elaborate more please?

Answer (score 1):

On the basis of the tags and language selection (perl) I am assuming you are using Selenium 1 RC - Perl

If that is the case you could do it this way

```
$sel->type_ok("upload-import-link", "\/home\/yourname\/Desktop\/filename.doc",'User enters the file path of the document to be uploaded');
$sel->click_ok("submit","user clicks on upload\/submit button");
```

Comment: I got this error. `Can't locate object method "type_ok" via package "WWW::Selenium"`. Are you sure `type_ok` is available in `WWW::Selenium`?

Comment: Yes you can check http://search.cpan.org/~mattp/Test-WWW-Selenium-1.25/lib/WWW/Selenium.pm

Comment: There is only `click` and `click_at`, no `click_ok`.

Comment: `click` and `click_at` are Selenium functions while `ok` is just a Perl Test Unit wrapper to make the `click` a test case.